# Regex delimiters put back into use

Tags: javascript, regex

I am a bit stuck on this, can't figure out how to re-insert the non-word characters ie. "-" and "!". I used regex as a way to split based on those delimiters but do need to retain the indices of the "-" and the "!" and re-introduce once I convert it back into a string from the array. The desired output is "e6t-r3s are r4y fun!" and so far I am getting:
'e6t r3s are r4y fun '

Write a function that takes a string and turns any and all "words" (see below) within that string of length 4 or greater into an abbreviation following the same rules.

abbreviate("elephant-rides are really fun!");

```
function abbreviate(string) {
    var array = string.split(/\W/); 
    var newArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {//iterates through each word
      var word = array[i];
      var abbrString = "";
      if (word.length >= 4) {
          //concat first index,count of indexes in between, last index
          var innerChar = word.substring(1, word.length - 1);
          var indCount = innerChar.length;
          var abbrWord = word.charAt(0) + indCount + word.charAt(word.length-1); 
          newArray.push(abbrWord);
        } else {
          newArray.push(word);
        }

    }
  return newArray.join(" ");
}
```

Comment: How about `delim=string.split(originalWord)[1]` for words with delimiters (e.g not the last word or duplicate)

Comment: At the end you do a join by a single space. Then it makes sense to split by `" "` too, instead of `/\W/` which stands for non-word characters.

Answer (score 1):

Your code can be much simpler if you will use ability to [pass a function to String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Syntax):

```js
function abbreviate(str) {
    return str.replace(/[a-z]{4,}/ig, function (word) {
        return word[0] + (word.length - 2) + word[word.length - 1];
    })
}

console.log(abbreviate("elephant-rides are really fun!"));
console.log(abbreviate("Accessibility"));
```

Comment: Appreciated! I'm a beginner at this, and will look try to understand your code...though it is failing one of the specs, "Accessibility" - Expected: 'A11y', instead got: 'Ac10y'

Comment: @chyltse. You can add the `i` modifier after the `g` modifier of the regex. Or use `\w`. Another version using groups is: `str.replace(/(\w)(\w{2,})(\w)/g, (_, a, b, c) => a + b.length + c);`

Comment: @chyltse fixed mixed case issue

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes it is not because original questions contains "string of length 4 or greater" condition

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes true, forgot about regex quantifier :)